# How to attach something to the windscreen bracket in Peugeot Expert/Toyota Proace 2016?

Tags: windshield, mirrors

I have a van without rear-view mirror and I bought something to attach to the rear-view mirror bracket on the windscreen. The attachment system looks like this:

[image: Bracket]
<sub>(source: [avrmobiles.co.uk](https://www.avrmobiles.co.uk/acatalog/pswbp35-peugeot-bracket.jpg))</sub>

The three small hooks are supposed to grab around the metal bracket on the windscreen.

However, I have tried attaching it pretty hard and it won't go. I'm afraid of pushing against the glass even harder.

How would a professional do this? Do they support the windscreen from the other side when attaching something like this, or is it safe to just push as hard as needed?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the mount is intended to be fitted over the receiving "button" rotated to 60degrees, then twisted clockwise into position.
Ref. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5CHUvNcS7A

Comment: Oh wow I think you're right! Thanks! I'll try it tonight.